# Custom counter in \state in algorithmic package

Tags: counters, algorithmic

I am using the algorithm package. Every time I type \state, it generates a new enumerated line.

What I want to do, is that to change the counter after x lines, so that the next line is $t$.

Here is a MWE (using something like \setcounter{state}{t} does not work):

```
\documentclass[authoryear,a4paper, 12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}

begin{algorithm}
        \caption{
            \label{alg:leftmost-leaves}
            Leftmost-leaves algorithm for an all-good cake.
        }
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE{A cake.}
            \ENSURE{A phrase.}
            \STATE  In period $1$,
            
            \STATE  In period 2

            \STATE In period t,
            Similarly
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro printing the line number is called `\ALC@lno`. You can redefine this temporarily to print the required string.

To undo the effect afterwards you can store the original definition in another macro and copy that definition back. The definition can be found in `algorithmic.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\ALC@linenosize \arabic{ALC@line}\ALC@linenodelimiter}}{}%
}
```

The part that prints the line number consists of three components: the size of the line number, the counter and the delimiter (by default `:`). For the redefinition we can change that into:

```
\ALC@linenosize $t$\ALC@linenodelimiter
```

This redefinition should be placed just before the line with the changed counter, and at the end of that line the original definition can be restored.

Because the macro name `\ALC@lno` contains an `@` sign you need to surround any code using that name with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,a4paper, 12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}

% store the original definition from algorithmic.sty
\makeatletter
\newcommand\origalclno{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\ALC@linenosize \arabic{ALC@line}\ALC@linenodelimiter}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{algorithm}
        \caption{
            \label{alg:leftmost-leaves}
            Leftmost-leaves algorithm for an all-good cake.
        }
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE{A cake.}
            \ENSURE{A phrase.}
            \STATE  In period $1$,
            
            \STATE  In period 2\makeatletter\renewcommand\ALC@lno{\ALC@linenosize $t$\ALC@linenodelimiter}\makeatother

            \STATE In period t,\makeatletter\let\ALC@lno\origalclno\makeatother
            
            \STATE In period 4
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the line counter gets increased as normal, so the next line is 4.

Comment: You're a life-saver, thanks.